# CSS text overflowing its container: width not fitting content - Solution without width: fit-content

Tags: html, css

I'm scratching my head around a tricky CSS problem. Could you help me to understand what's going on? My code is very simple:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; overflow: auto; padding: 10px; background-color: blue">
    <div style="background-color: red">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, it's just text wrapped inside a 300px scrollable container.

My problem is the following: I have remarked that when the content inside the scrollable container is bigger than the container due to an overflowing text, the width of the inner element does not grow properly.

Here are a few screenshots to illustrate this:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the width of the text inside my scrollable container does not fit its content (I'd like the red background to cover the full text).
That looks weird to me, as this is only happening for overflowing texts, not manually sized divs (if I put a 500px within my 300px container, width is good).

I've found solutions on the web using width: fit-content, width: intrinsic, … but that does not seem well supported by old browsers.

Could you help me to understand why my text is not growing in width, and what are the possible solutions to avoid that? That would be very kind,

Thanks a lot

Comment: You simply mean that, the text should fit the div without scroll is it?

Comment: I mean : the div containing the text should contain its text (be more than 300px wide)

Comment: chnage style overflow:hidden and check was that your expecting? Or else your expecting the whole text to be fit iin within 300px div is it?

Comment: It crops my content; I'd like to have the full text with a scroll, but over a red background

Comment: Ah you need the whole text to be highlighted?

Comment: Yes, but in a 300px container with scroll

Answer (score 0):

you can add a inline Element for that, Hope below code helps you

```html
<div style="width: 300px; overflow: auto; padding: 10px; background-color: blue">
    <div>
    <span style="background-color:red">                   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just make the inner div `display:inline`?

Comment: That's violating purpose of the div I guess :) , Anyway yes its a solution too, let me modify the answer. Thank You

Comment: That's awesome thanks. And, do you know why it behaves like that with a block element?

Comment: Block level elements are always for structuring and Grouping set of elements.

Comment: The problem with that solution is the outer div does not grow. It is still smaller than the contained element :/

Comment: Yah, It will not grow you have given a fixed width and overflow content on scroll. Now what exactly want to happen, I didn't get you.

Comment: I'd like to have the text fully covered by a red background, and the outer div should wrap the entire text :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233220/discussion-between-rifkan-razak-and-alexis-clarembeau).